# Users adding answers to old questions

Tags: discussion

As part of suggested  edits queue i got an answer to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154426/invalid-field-count-for-aggregateresult/261748#261748) question which is more than 2 years old and has an accepted answer.

What do we do in these cases to - accept or reject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were two different reviewable events there.

One was a "Late Answer" by a new user - that's a new answer to an old question that needs to be reviewed by the user base.

The other was a "Suggested Edit" by m Peixoto to that answer. Because the edit corrected the entirely absent code formatting, I think it was rightfully accepted. I personally am much more skeptical of small cosmetic edits to very old posts, but I think it's valuable to address shortcomings in new posts in that way.

However, since the answer itself was just a code paste that had no connection to the question other than also using Aggregate SOQL, I've deleted it.

Comment: Thanks @david, Just did not know what to do since it was not adding any value